# drop down list with value from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to C# asp.net web form, search all the tread, but i did not have a answer.

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString; //read from web.config.
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
con.Open();
SqlDataReader myReader = null;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from gender", con);
myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (myReader.Read())
{
    ddlmarrital.DataSource = myReader;         //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
    ddlmarrital.DataTextField = "field";       // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
    ddlmarrital.DataValueField = "ID";         // to retrive specific  textfield name 
    ddlmarrital.DataBind();                    //binding dropdownlist
}
con.Close();
```

table1 (Gender) 1.male 2.female.

Mastertable1 (Name "ABC").(Gender "Male).(Address "ABC")

I want to display a value (Mastertable1.gender) that saved, and if i want to change the value i can use the dropdownlist to select.

Comment: Remove the loop. Not needed, however, what is the problem?

Comment: I can't get the value on "Mastertable1".gender to display on the dropdownlist.

Comment: But if you need values from MasterTable then why you query the Gender table?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What is the current result? Post a screenshot if possible.

Comment: Hi Steve, Might be I am using the wrong method. My intention to display mastertable value on the field. And if I want to change, i can change to value in the table1.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping a SqlDataSource object on the web form from the ToolBox would be more easy. Set the Dropdownlist to the sqldatasource object and configure the sqldatasource.

If you must do it in code, remove your while loop.

```
...
myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
ddlmarrital.DataSource = myReader;                 
ddlmarrital.DataTextField = "field";
ddlmarrital.DataValueField = "ID";
ddlmarrital.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following. I refactored a bit your code and I use the `using` statement for both `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects, because they both implement the `IDisposable` interface. Specifically, they use unmanaged resources and this resources, which should be released as soon as possible after you have done your job with them. This is why the `Dispose` method should be called. A convenient way to do so is to use the `using` statement, like below.

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString; 

using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    var commandText = "SELECT * FROM gender";

    using(var command = new SqlCommand(commandText,connection))
    {
        ddlmarrital.DataSource = command.ExecuteReader();
        ddlmarrital.DataTextField = "field";       
        ddlmarrital.DataValueField = "ID";  
        ddlmarrital.DataBind();         
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christos, the dropdownlist work, but how you set the to read from Mastertable1(Gender "Male) to display as the default value?

Comment: I don't get you. What do you mean by saying to read from? How is this associated with the default (selected) value? If you only need the latter, please state it clear. Otherwise you should explain more thoroughly what are you looking for.

Comment: i want a  dropdown list with Mastertable1's value. is that possible, or i am totally wrong.

Comment: What is the `Mastertable`? Is it a table in your database? If yes, then why in your sql statement you use the table called `gender`? Am I correct or I have understood it wrong?

Comment: I am calling gender table because I want it to show on drop down list. Mastertable is a table that content gender detail. On my form, I want to use dropdownlist to change the field, if the gender on mastertable is wrong.  Hope I explain correctly. Thanks.